# Environment variable refresh by editing bashrc not working

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, environment variables can be edited by profile or rc files, such as `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` in integrated terminal.

However, when I tried to run a Jupyter notebook file on ssh-remote server, the edited environment variables were not reflected to the `.ipynb` file even though I ran `source ~/.bashrc` command, restarted `VScode`, and deleted my ssh session.

What is the method to refresh shell of the remote server while running VS Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to restart the remote server you are connecting to, by using the `Kill VS Code Server On Host...` command from the command palette (CTRL+SHIFT+P), selecting the host you experience the problem with, then closing and restarting VS Code.

I had the same problem today, and this worked for me. The VS Code server does not seem to update the environment variables e.g. from `.bashrc` dynamically.